# Merge two different data frames by same column in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1 =

```
A            ANTS         AGE
0            ABC           18
1            ABC           25
3            ABC           24   
2            DEF           20
```

df2 =

```
ANTS          LOC
ABC           WIND
DEF           FIND
```

My output should be

df3 =

```
    A            ANTS         AGE    LOC
    0            ABC           18    WIND 
    1            ABC           25    WIND
    3            ABC           24    WIND
    2            DEF           20    FIND
```

How can we merge df1 and df2 to get df3 effectively ?

Comment: See: [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='ANTS')`